# C#5 async method completed event.

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

I have an asynchronous method like this

```
public async void Method()
{
    await // Long run method
}
```

When Im calling this method can I have a event when this Method completed?

```
public void CallMethod()
{
    Method();
    // Here I need an event once the Method() finished its process and returned.
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you need that? Do you need to wait for completion? That works like this:

```
public async Task Method() //returns Task
{
    await // Long run method
}

public void CallMethod()
{
    var task = Method();

    //here you can set up an "event handler" for the task completion
    task.ContinueWith(...);

    await task; //or await directly
}
```

If you cannot use await and really need to use an event-like pattern, use `ContinueWith`. You can think of that as adding an event handler for task completion.